# Protobuf-net is not serializing? Output nearly plain text

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I'm a beginner with protobuf and I'm having a problem I hope you can help me with:

I tried out [the example][1] of the protobuf-net page and got it running. I extended it, that not only one person is stored, but another data class which holds a list of 10000 persons. Then I serialized that data class and had a look into the output. I expected to see some binary stuff and was surprised to see nearly everything as plain text:

```
 π`Fred
Flat 1The Meadows
 π`Fred
Flat 1The Meadows
 π`Fred
Flat 1The Meadows
 π`Fred
Flat 1The Meadows
 π`Fred
...
```

My code is pretty simple:

```
namespace SNSClient.Assets.Scripts.GamePlay.Testing
{
    [ProtoContract]
    class Person 
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Name {get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public Address Address {get;set;}
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class Address 
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Line1 {get;set;}
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Line2 {get;set;}
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class MyProtoDataHolder
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public List<Person> persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For serialization:

```
List<Person> dataList = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var person = new Person {
    id = 12345, Name = "Fred",
    Address = new Address {
    Line1 = "Flat 1",
    Line2 = "The Meadows"
    }
    };

    dataList.Add(person);
}
var data = new MyProtoDataHolder() {persons = dataList};

using (var file = File.Create(Application.dataPath + "/dataList.bin"))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(file, data);
}
```

I'm expecting that I'm missing something, 'cause the size of the output file is not what I would expect.

Thanks for help!

Comment: since `Name` and `Address` are strings, the values will be readable.  If you dont want that you can use a [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: If you deserialize your file, are the classes thereby restored identical to the originals?  Or is there some actual difference?

Comment: *why* do you think what it *is* serializing is not correct?

Comment: @Peter: I'm expecting that all data is in some kind of unreadable binary format. But I think Plutonix has the right answer for me. Since the values are strings, they will be later readable in the output.

Comment: @ffyhlkain Why?  What part of the protobuf documentation made you infer that?  UTF8 *is* a binary format.  Nothing in the documentation suggests that everything should be unreadable.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Well, I'm expecting that a serializer could reuse duplicate string values, so the file size may be smaller. But you're right, that it doesn't necessarily mean that it's also unreadable.

Comment: @ffyhlkain yes, there's lots of things it *could* do; and if the docs *said* it did that I'd have a concern.  I can see nothing in the docs that say anything like that, if you've read that somewhere, please provide a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is dominated by text. The protobuf wire format encodes text as UTF-8, so it makes sense that:

1. the files are *almost* readable (and contain the original text values clearly visible to most text editors)
2. the file size isn't much different to the original content

Basically: looks fine to me. If you want it compressed, run it through something like `GZipStream` or `DeflateStream` too (in both directions, obviously). As a side note: if your *real* data will have lots of duplicate data, protobuf-net has some opt-in flags to allow things like object and string re-use (storing just a token, not the entire string each time) - however, it will be awkward to read that into other protocol buffers libraries (i.e. not protobuf-net), as this functionality is not part of the core specification.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Marc for pointing that out with the opitmization flags. I was looking for exact that, as I'll have several duplicate data and that I want to have optmized.

Comment: @ffyhlkain `AsReference` in particular